# Yearling Badges broken here on MSE?

Tags: support, badges

I just received *three* Yearling badges in the span of a few minutes...

> [image]

That seems odd, is this a bug or intended behavior?

Comment: The badge doesn’t check which year you earn the rep so if you have a 101 rep account for five years and then get 1000 rep in a week, you’ll get five badges in that week.

Comment: @Catija sounds like a possible bug then in how its handled.  :/

Comment: Did you just earn 600 rep from the recalc?

Comment: @Catija can't tell, because the system won't show me the recalcs on Meta.SE (I'm not a moderator here.)  Shows me my recalc on Ask Ubuntu though (where I have moderator insights)

Comment: Looking at your question scores, about +600 is the right ballpark.

Comment: If you want a rough estimate of your increase, just look at your previous rep in SEDE. It might be slightly off (as in 3 days off), but it'll at least give you an indicator

Comment: @ThomasWard it is always handled this way.  If you are a member of a site for 5 years but have 101 rep.  Then provide some really good answers or asking some really good questions in the span of a few weeks and jump to 1101 rep, you will see the yearling badge 5 times (5 years with an average of 200 rep per year).

Comment: > Global Recalc: question upvote value change old rep = 668, new rep = 1245

Comment: That explains that.  Thanks @Catija